# trying to update file time/date on a file in another folder in windows

Tags: windows, cmd, copy

I am trying to update the time and date (to "now") on a file that's in another folder on Windows 10.

I am in `c:\temp\folder1`  and there is a file in `c:\temp\folder2` called `foo.txt`

I would like to update the timestamp on `foo.txt`  to be "now"

I can use `copy /b foo.txt +,,`  while in folder2, and that works fine

but if i am in folder1, it makes a copy in folder1.   (  `copy /b ..\folder2\foo.txt +,,`  )

I assume the `+,,` is wrong when the destination is another folder?

I am sure I am missing something...  any help would be appreciated!

Is there a way to do this programmatically (C++)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cd c:\temp\folder2 & copy /b foo.txt +,, & cd c:\temp\folder1
```

You can change '&' with '&&' if you want the second command to execute only if the first exited successfully.